# How do I pass by reference in Scala? with a ListBuffer

Tags: list, scala, reference, functional-programming, buffer

I want to pass an object in Scala by reference.

The pseudo code is something like

```
var list1 = List(//stuff in here)
var list2 = List(//stuff in here).toBuffer

list1.forEach(element => foo(element,list2)


def foo(element,list2){
  remove something from list 2
}
```

so on each iteration of the forEach, list2 would be different :/
What would be the best way to do this on scala. Thanks :D

Comment: The "best way to do this in scala" would be to not do it at all. Using mutable containers is almost _always_ a wrong idea when writing scala. 
But if you insist on doing it your way, you will have to show more code, because everything is passed by reference in scala, so your problem is with something else (I am guessing, you are using a wrong function to mutate your buffer). BTW, there is no `forEach` function ... and your paretheses are unbalanced.

Comment: Scala doesn't support pass-by-reference. Arguments are either pass-by-value or call-by-name. If you need pass-by-reference, you can try C++ or C♯, which both support it.

Answer (score 0):

A List().toBuffer will generate a ArrayBuffer which itself is mutable. So you don't have to use var.
The key thing is that what's the code piece in "remove something from list 2". Here's a sample code to do this without problem:

```
val a = List(1,2)
val b = List(1,3,2).toBuffer
a.foreach(ele => foo(ele, b))
println(b)

def foo(ele: Int, b: mutable.Buffer[Int]): Unit = {
    b -= ele
}
```

In the `foo`, use BufferLike.-= method to remove inside the Buffer of it, then it would be fine if this is what you want. The code will generate output:

```
ArrayBuffer(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  var list1 = List(1, 2, 3)
  var list2 = List(1, 2, 3, 4).toBuffer
  list1.foreach(
     element =>
        list2 = foo(element, list2)
  )
}



def foo(element: Int, list2: Buffer[Int]) = {
      println("list2 length:" + list2.length)
      list2.foreach(println)
      var newlist = list2.drop(element)
      newlist
}
```

Something like this ? It's not a good way as Dima said.